# Trying to obtain the tag of a button in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, view

for an assignment I am trying to obtain the tag of a button from the story board, this works inside of my button handlers however outside of the handler, an error is thrown which is confusing me. Code below:

```
// Executed on image button click
@IBAction func facebookButton(_ sender: Any) {
    openWebPage(url: faceBookURL)
    let foo = view.viewWithTag(1)! as! NSButton // WORKS INSIDE OF BUTTON HANDLER
    foo.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("tumblrIcon"))
}
```

However, when I try to run this line outside of the handler, i get the following error:

> Value of type '(NSView, NSView.ToolTipTag, NSPoint,
>   UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> String' (aka '(NSView, Int, CGPoint,
>   Optional) -> String') has no member
>   'viewWithTag'

Any suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call `viewWithTag` on something that isn't an `NSView`. Can you share the code that's not working?

Comment: Intersting, it looks like your code thinks you mean [`view(_:stringForToolTip:point:userData:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1483693-view). Posting the other code will help us figure out the problem.

Comment: I think I may have found the solution be it I am unsure why this works. I placed that section of code in its own function and it seems to run fine, for some reason it seems like the issue was when the code was simply in the class and not in a function?

Comment: In general, Swift does not like code that's outside of a function/method. You shouldn't put code inside the class body itself.